# jQueryUI Ajax.NET Postback Bug

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I have [this](http://pastebin.org/219615) ASP.NET page with ASP.NET UpdatePanel and jQueryUI droppable and sortable components. The page works fine in all browsers, but doesn't in Internet Explorer (IE8 tested).

After I try to call ASP.NET AJAX event (by pressing my asp.net button inside the UpdatePanel) my sortable list stops working properly inside IE browser and the browser throws the following error:

> Message: Unspecified error.
> Line: 145
> Char: 186
> Code: 0 URI: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

I found out that the problem is caused by the code on line 66:

```
$("#droppable").droppable();
```

If I comment it out, the sortable list works fine after ajax postbacks. But it doesn't make sense.

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Thanks.

P.S. I am using jQueryUI **1.8.1** and jQuery **1.4.2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in JQuery - I think there is a fix where you redefine the offset function to work under IE:

http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4918

Cheers

Comment: awesome, thanks. Destroying sortable and droppable elements before the AJAX post-back solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
        <style type="text/css">
                #sortable
                {
                        list-style-type: none;
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                        border: solid 1px #999999;
                }
                #sortable li
                {
                        margin: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
                        padding-left: 1.5em;
                        font-size: 1em;
                        height: auto;
                        border: dotted 1px #999999;
                        background-color: #dddddd;
                }
                #sortable li:hover
                {
                        background-color: #aaaaaa;
                }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="srptManager">
                        <Scripts>
                                <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" />
                                <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" />
                        </Scripts>
                </asp:ScriptManager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPanel" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                                <ul id="sortable">
                                        <li>Item 1</li>
                                        <li>Item 2</li>
                                        <li>Item 3</li>
                                        <li>Item 4</li>
                                        <li>Item 5</li>
                                </ul>
                                <div id="droppable" style="background-color: black">
                                        Drop Here</div>
                                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAjaxRefresh" Text="Go" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
 
                <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
                        // *******Solution Here*******
                        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
 
                        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                                if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
                                        jqueryStuff();
                                }
                        }
 
                        function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
                                $("#sortable").sortable("destroy");
                                $("#droppable").droppable("destroy");
                        }
 
                        function jqueryStuff() {
                                $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $("#sortable").disableSelection();
                                        $("#sortable").sortable();
                                        // ******Problem at this line******
                                        $("#droppable").droppable();
                                });
                        }
 
                        jqueryStuff();
                </script>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pastebin link is dead

Comment: Is a dead link for a 9-year old bug fix a good reason for your downvote? If you still got this problem, there's plenty information in the question and accepted answer for you to solve it.